# Do Catalan-like series have an explicit formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

The Catalan numbers satisfy the recurrence relation
$$
C_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{C_i C_{n-i}} \hspace{1 cm} C_1 = 1.
$$
Using generating functions, it is possible to use this recursion to find the explicit formula for the Catalan numbers:
$$
C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}.
$$

I recently ran into a series that satisfies a very similar recursive formula to the Catalan numbers, namely
$$
D_{n} = \frac{2}{n^2-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{D_i D_{n-i}} \hspace{1 cm} D_1 = 1.
$$
This got me thinking. It is known that not all series with a quadratic recursive formula have an explicit formula, and the Logistic map ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map ) is one example of this. The Catalan numbers, however, do have a nice explicit formula, despite the fact that their recursive formula is quadratic. Is there a general theorem/argument that shows that all "Catalan-like" sequences, such as my sequence $D_n$, have an explicit formula? Or is the fact that the Catalan numbers have such a formula just  a lucky "miracle"?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a miracle that there's an explicit formula for Catalan numbers - it's more that the recursive formula is very nice in that case since it is a convolution, giving the equation $f(x) = x + f(x)^2$ for the Catalan generating function.  The recursion for $D_n$ is not as nice, but you can at least use it to find a second-order differential equation for the ogf.  It might be hard to solve, though.